# Is it possible to pass a custom "notify_url" to paypal using the new PHP SDK?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I was wondering, 
Is there any way to pass a custom "notify_url" to paypal using the new PayPal-PHP-SDK? 
*I used to do that with the old way as one of the post variables.

If not - 
What is the best way to deal with multiple sites using the same paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

There is this option if you do ordinary one time payment ( not recurring ), just youse parameter

> PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL

and replace 0 with number of product.

For recurring payments you must use the IPN url that is set inside a paypal account. How to modify this IPN url you will find here - [check this paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/). After that inside this IPN url must implement a server script that are checked is the recurring subscription is canceled by the user

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't solve my problem.  I'm looking for a way to define the IPN URL dynamicaly outside the paypal account.   I used to add the "notify_url" parameter to the post variables but now I'm using the new PHP-SDK (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/).   Do you have any idea how to set that when I'm preparing the payment?

Answer (score 0):

You can call function "setNotifyUrl" from PHP SDK in order to set the notify_url:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/2afc181f50caf1a1da1f2dbf6742dc39dbbc13e3/lib/PayPal/Api/CartBase.php#L314